# Java StringBuilder: Newline after x Chars without splitting up words

Tags: java, string, newline, stringbuilder

```
public class Ex7
    {
        //constructor
        public static String s = "1234567890123456789 In the output words on a line are separated by precisely one space verb+' '+,\nlines are separated by\n\nprecisely one newline (so no trailing spaces) and";
        public static int width = 20;

        public static void format(){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int start = 0; start < s.length(); start += width){
                int cursor = start + width - 1;
                boolean w = true;
                while(w){
                    if(cursor-1 < s.length()){
                        if((s.charAt(cursor) == ' ') || (s.charAt(cursor)== '\t')){
                            if(start + width -1 < s.length()){
                                sb.append(s.substring(start, cursor));
                                sb.append("\n");
                                w = false;
                            }
                            else{
                                sb.append("\n");
                                sb.append(s.substring(start));
                                w = false;
                            }      
                        }
                        else{
                            cursor--;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                       sb.append("\n");
                       sb.append(s.substring(start));
                       w = false; 
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
            }
    }
```

Hey guys,

my goal is, to format a given String s, so that there is a newline after every 20th character (in this case). Words may not be split up (if the 20th character is part of a word, newline has to be inserted before that word.)

my output with this example-string:

```
1234567890123456789
In the output words
on a line are
ted by precisely
 space verb+'
nes are separated


precisely one
ine (so no trailing

spaces) and
```

the wanted output by exercise:

```
01234567890123456789
In the output words
on a line are
separated by
precisely one space
\verb+' '+, lines
are separated by
precisely one
newline (so no
trailing spaces)
and
```

We may not use the Scanner class or thrid-party-libraries.
Any suggestions?

Sincerely,
FLiiX

Comment: Since you can't split words on multiple lines, it might be simplest to start by splitting the input string into a `String[]`, by using whitespace (spaces and newlines in this case) as a separator; e.g. `String[] words = s.split("\\s+");`. After you've done this, you can simply iterate over the `words` array and append content lines into the `StringBuilder`, keeping in mind the 20-char-per-line limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); )
{
   if(!(s.substring(i+21).equals(" ")))
   {
      int j = i+21;
      do
      {
         j--;
      }while(!(s.substring(j).equals(" ")));
      System.out.print(s.substring(i, j) + "\n");
      i += i - j;
   }else{
      System.out.print(s.substring(i, i+20) + "\n");
      i += 20;
   }
}
```

I haven't tested this yet but I believe it would serve your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like this.

```
public String splitString(String s, int maxWidth) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + maxWidth)) != -1) {
        sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```